# Nested parameter expansion not working as expected

Tags: zsh, variable-expansion, parameter-expansion

[zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) says:

`${name}`

> The value, if any, of the parameter name is substituted.

It then also says:

> If a ${...} type parameter expression or a $(...) type command substitution ***is used in place of name above***, it is expanded first and the result is used as if it were the value of name.

My question is why does the following not work then, assuming I am understanding it correctly, i.e. variable names can be nested?

```
echo $ab $fooz           
foo 123
echo "${${ab}z}"         
zsh: bad substitution
```

```
Expected:
123
```

Comment: Simple parameter expressions can not be nested. The resolution is done once from left to right and from top to bottom.

Comment: A zsh question should not be tagged `sh`. `sh` refers to the POSIX specification; zsh does not comply with that spec. (Moreover, the `sh` specification doesn't call for nested parameter expansion to be supported at all).

Comment: @Ulox What do you mean top to bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you expect `echo "${${ab}z}"` to do? I believe you wanted it to evaluate `${ab}` then append a literal `z` and then interpret the whole thing as if it were a variable name, thus ending up with `123`.

Here is your desired outcome with some steps that show us getting there:

```
$ ab=foo fooz=123
$ echo $ab $fooz
foo 123
$ echo ${(P)ab}

$ echo ${(P)ab}z
z
$ echo ${${(P)ab}z}
123
```

(Bash can do `${!ab}` but can't nest to do the final step. POSIX can't do anything of the sort.)

This uses Zsh's [parameter expansion `P` flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119442/87770).

Comment: FYI the reason this works is because `${${(P)name}...}` is treated as a special case by zsh. So in the example above, `${(P)ab}` isn't expanded on its own (it'd be blank as indicated). Instead, it's expanded along with `z` to yield `${fooz}` => 123. It's documented, albeit somewhat unclearly, in the last paragraph of the P flag in zshexpn(1). Here is the relevant comment in the source code: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/830d54e629e8e12eb5a219a65a013876662e7b3e/Src/subst.c#L2308-L2316